# Update Table Records based on Excel

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database that imports employees from an Excel file.

I have an `append` query that adds new employees and an `update` query that updates information on the current employee (i.e. Name Changes, Address, etc.).

I have a field on a table called `Departed` which I have to update manually between `yes` and `no` if an employee leaves.

I am trying to find a way that if the employee is not in Excel, then change their `Departed` record from `no` to `yes` in Access.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have imported/linked the Excel dataset as a table in your Access database, then you can update the `Departed` field using an `update` query with a `left join` from your database table to your Excel dataset, testing whether the records on the right of this join are `Null` (i.e. don't exist in the Excel dataset).

Such a query might look like this:

```
update Employees left join ExcelEmployees on Employees.ID = ExcelEmployees.ID
set Employees.Departed = -1
where ExcelEmployees.ID is null
```

This assumes that your database table is called `Employees`, your imported/linked Excel dataset is called `ExcelEmployees` and that there is a primary key field called `ID` which may be used to join the two.